# UICollectionViewCell block based selection

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I tried to implement a way to detect the selection of a tableview or collectionview without the need of the delegate method.

I used KVO for `selected`, but also when scrolling (the delegate call is not executed when scrolling) the `selected` property changes.

Do you have any idea how to do this?

My current code looks like this:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                     ofObject:(id)object
                       change:(NSDictionary *)change
                      context:(void *)context{
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"selected"])
    {

        if (self.selected) {
            dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                self.selected = NO;
            });
            [self cellPressed];
        }
    }
}
```

My init method contains:

```
[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"selected" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:nil];
```

And my dealloc method contains:

```
[self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"selected"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use tap gesture.put uiview on uicollectionviewcell and add tap gesture on it.

Comment: that actually changes the interaction with the scrollview